# How to read excel file xlsx to a grid view without oledb provider as it's not registered at godaddy server?

Tags: c#

In C#, How to read excel file xlsx to a grid view without oledb provider as it's not registered at godaddy server??

or is there a way to over come 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider which is not registered on the local machine on godaddy

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library in the past which does what you required.

Cheers Mike